# How to declare a base class for ThisDocument?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I want to put some base functionality into a base class where all my documents inherit from.
The question is, how can I declare this base class?

I tried with partial, abstract... but always get the error:

> Base class of mynamespace.ThisDocument differs from declared in other parts" ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately at the moment we don't know how you're *trying*  to declare `ThisDocument`. It looks like it's a partial class, and its multiple declarations conflict with each other. They should all specify the same base class.

Comment: From the error message it seems that ThisDocument is defined in more than one file (as partial class). You then have to change the base class in all files.

Comment: It's a VSTO declaration.
In designer it shows: public sealed partial class ThisDocument : Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.DocumentBase
But this stilll does not help me how to declare my base class ?

Comment: Then derive your base class from `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.DocumentBase` and change this line to `public sealed partial class ThisDocument : MyBaseClass`

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you've got a problem with partial classes. Can't see your code but you are probably declaring something like:

```
partial class Derived : MyBase    // Your code
{
}
```

Somewhere in the generated code there will be:

```
partial class Derived : TheirBase // Generated code
{
}
```

When these two are merged into a single class, you get an error because in C# you are only allowed a single base class.

You could write

```
partial class Derived : TheirBase  // Your code
{
}
```

so the two agree, or

```
partial class Derived // Your code
{
}
```

which takes the base class in the other file by default.

The best solution is to derived your base class from the predefined one:

```
class MyBase : TheirBase
{
}
```

and then change the generated code to use it:

```
partial class Derived : MyBase // Generated code
{
}
```

Tampering with generated code can be risky, since if it regenerated you lose your changes, but it should be okay here.